# Best practice sharing a Openapi yaml between Backend and Frontend

Tags: maven, npm, openapi, openapi-generator

in my new project we are using Openapi to share the API endpoints with each other. At the moment the yaml is part of the backend project and we copy it the frontend to create the client interface with the openapi generator. No the plan is to push the yaml into its own repository and publish it to our Nexus.

The backend is sprint-boot java based with maven and the frontend is react with npm.

1. Questions: if we publish the yaml to nexus (which worked easiely) how can we use it in the backend as dependency to create server part? Since we published just the yaml, maven tries to find a jar.
2. Questions: is this good practice or is there any better way to do this.